# Добавление текста на ссылку с картинкой

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<li><a href="../images/fullsize/Agave.jpg" class="zoom" title="image1" onclick=""><img src="../images/thumbs/Agave.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
```

при клике изображение увеличиваеться(есть javascript который вместо перехода по ссылке подменивает изображение,этот javascript был скачен),однако имееться задача так же добавить текст на уже увеличенное изображение,второй день мучаюсь,помогите гуру:)

Comment: [tsya.ru](http://tsya.ru)

Comment: спасибо конечно,но орфографию я буду учить с помощью google

Answer (score 1):

Как сделать с помощью css не знаю а вот с помощью javascript примерно так:

javascript:

```
function div()

{
    var text=document.getElementById("block");
    text.style.display="block";
}
```

css:

```
#block
{
    position:absolute;
    display:none
}
```

html:

```
<img src="" onClick="div()">
<div id="block">text</div>
```

Comment: спасибо,но проблему решил другой альтернативой funcybox,в ней можно кастомизировать изображения,надписи и так далее

Comment: @Роман Соколов  - возможно вам будет интересно :) http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/GA5WF/